# Why NSURLConnection is slower than stringWithContentsOfURL?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I have a simple json file on http://img.soulapp.cn/appips.json. I test it on Postman, the time is about 200ms.

I tried

```
NSLog(@"%f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://img.soulapp.cn/appips.json"]];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:req queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
       NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
       NSLog(@"%f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);
 }];
```

time is 4s.

I tried

```
[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://img.soulapp.cn/appips.json"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]
```

time is 200ms.

Why `NSURLConnection` is slower than `stringWithContentsOfURL`?

How to improve it or can i make `stringWithContentsOfURL` safer because it's synchronize method?

Comment: My guess is that the queue doesn't start the download immediately, but `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` is deprecated as of iOS 9, and the whole `NSURLConnection` system is considered a legacy loading system that you should migrate away from. What happens if you use an `NSURLSession` instead?

Comment: Also, it may depend on many other factors not mentioned by the Michael. Usually when you want to test the speed of certain component, you should at least perform thousand operation on it, and take the average. Running the resource dependent code once and comparing will not show the actual result.

Comment: `stringWithContentsOfURL:` is not intended for loading remote resources.